# Is this "note to self" appropriate to post on Server Fault?

Tags: support, questions

I don't know my way around Server Fault so I thought I'd ask first.

I am in the process of taking down a Windows Server, and had to back up a number of Subversion repositories (>10) from there.

To do this automatically using `svndump`, you have to build a small script that lists all the directories in your repositories dir, and runs a `svndump` on all of them.

The syntax to do this varies from Windows to Windows. Because I need to do this 1-2 times a year max, I have to look up how to do it on the Internet every time, and usually try 3-4 different MSDN pages, blog entries, and forum posts until one solution finally works.

Is it appropriate to start a question on Server Fault named "How to dump multiple repositories on various operating systems", make it CW, and post my answer for Windows 2003 Server? Partly so I know where to look for it next time, and partly obviously because it would be useful for others as well.

There is no such question on Server Fault at the moment.

Comment: I think that would save a lot of people a lot of time, if written agreeably.

Comment: See also [Is it poor etiquette to answer your own question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question) and [Moving a personal technical blog to stackoverflow / serverfault](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stackoverflow-serverfault)

Comment: I've definitely done things like this.  It also helps when other people in your company can Google the issue and get a good answer.

Comment: FWIW: I wouldn't make it CW

Answer (score 15):

Simply phrase it as a Jeopardy question and give others the time to answer it for you.

You never know, you might learn something new in the process!

For the rest I don't see any objections

Comment: Cheers @ivo, done: http://serverfault.com/questions/129351/how-to-dump-multiple-subversion-repositories-at-once-on-various-systems I posted my answer straight away but there may be more elegant solutions, in which case I'll happily delete mine.

Comment: +1. I agree. it's in accordance with the "wiki" character of the trilogy.

Comment: @Pekka don't delete it. Just accept the one that worked better instead and then comment on your own answer that something else worked better because of x, y, and z.  Someone else may one day consider the same technique, in which case the keywords in your post will likely be a better google match, thus making it easier for them to find the better solution.

Comment: I would say, as long as you indicate that you're providing an answer in accordance with the FAQ, you could go ahead and answer right away.  You do risk people who "don't get it" giving you a downvote, but you're interested in archiving the answer, not getting rep anyway.  Explaining what you are doing might help with the erroneous downvotes though.

Comment: True, I could have made a difference between answering and accepting your own answer